# how to read the symbol ～

Tags: readings

I found this sentence:

密漁グループは20～40代の男12人

*The sealife poaching group consisted of 12 men in their 20s to 40s.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASP2M53N1P2MIIPE012.html?iref=comtop_7_07

Since I can read better than speak, I was wondering how to read the ～, so I looked it up here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Interpunct

and I found

*To indicate ranges (5時〜6時, from 5 o'clock to 6 o'clock; 東京〜大阪 Tokyo to Osaka). In such cases it may be read as ...kara...made (...から...まで)*

Does that mean the reading sounds like this

みつりょうグループはにじゅう から よんじゅう まで だいのおとこじゅうに にん

or is it

みつりょうグループはにじゅう から よんじゅうだい まで のおとこじゅうに にん

or possibly even

みつりょうグループはにじゅうだい から よんじゅうだい まで のおとこじゅうに にん

Comment: Your last two attempts are correct. にじゅうからよんじゅうまでだい sounds strange.